# I would like to populate the fields in suitelet form when i change the particular field without netsuite login

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am having one suitelet form. In that form i need to populate the field values when i change the customer name. For example if i select one customer, then the related information about the customer should populate in the corresponding field. I am using the nlapiLoadRecord in client script. But it is not supported in suitelet form when it is used without login.

How can i populate the fields in suitelet form.

Answer (score -1):

Write a router on your suitelet.

A) Do a GET route which loads the form, this form links a client script with form.setScript().

B) Do a GET + parameter route which takes the user id and spits out the desired data.

On the client script set the onfieldchanged function to call the suitelet with the user id, and then populate the data.